# Mavericks notification center like view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks

I'm making a drag and drop application for mac. I want to be able to drag a window to the edge of the screen and have a few slide over, like the notification center in Mavericks and drop the window in it.

I'm having some trouble figuring out where to start. Any ideas and sample code would be awesome.

Comment: Not sure which particular effect you're looking for - have the whole Desktop slide to the left when the notification center is shown?

Comment: yeah. I want the desktop to slide over and show my view. Into which i can drop windows.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to slide the actual desktop to one side and I don't even have a clue how Apple implements the effect for Notification Center.

However, one way of doing something similar that comes to mind would be to

- grab a screenshot of the Desktop with all its windows
- make your own window the size of the screen
- put the Desktop snapshot in a layer the size of the screen on top of that window
- slide that layer to the left,
- perform whatever custom drawing/handling you need in that revealed area of your own window.